# How to connect local folder to Git repository and start making changes on branches?

Tags: git, version-control, repository, gitlab, collaboration

I'm new to source control; in the past, I've manually backed up copies of files and made changes on clones then transferred changes manually to master files once debugged. I realize this is similar to how branches work with Git repositories, however I've never used one.

I downloaded Git and made an account on GitLab, and started a new project. My site is hosted on a local server and my files are saved locally. How do I connect these files to a Git repository and continue developing with branches?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

To register a project as a local Git repository the first thing you need to do is perform the following command at your **project root**:

```
git init
```

This will create a `.git` folder at your project root and will allow you to start using Git in that repository.

---

If you want to "push" your local Git repository to a remote Git server (in your case, to GitLab), you'll need to perform the following command first:

```
git remote add origin <Repository_Location>
```

You can call `origin` whatever you like, really, but `origin` is the standard name for Git remote repositories. `<Repository_Location>` is the URL to your remote repository. For example, if I had a new project called `MyNewProject` that I wanted to push to GitLab, I'd perform:

```
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/Harmelodic/MyNewProject.git
```

You can then "push" your changes from your local machine to your remote repo using the following command:

```
git push origin <branch_name>
```

where branch name is the name of the branch you want to push, e.g. `master`.

---

You can find a [good beginners guide to Git here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics).

Comment: Thanks for the info! So my site is still hosted on my local server; so I can create a branch remote and it'll add it locally and vice versa? Do I have to create two sites (clones of each other, to do live testing)? Does the branch connect to the live site?

Comment: So If I have a script that builds the same files in the repo, I can use this to commit changes without having to clone the repo first?

Comment: I am trying to push a new branch however running the last command results in `error: src refspec develop does not match any.` 
 `error: failed to push some refs to [...]`

Comment: I had to commit a file and also do `git branch <branch>` first

Comment: error: src refspec main does not match any

Answer (score 1):

Idk if necessary, but I've always named my local folder the same as the remote repo.

Also, prior to a git push, I try to:

`git pull origin master`

in order to get the latest code in the repository. Then I can port in my changes and commit.

Total text from GitHub:

```
echo "# xyz_repo" >> README.md

git init

git add README.md

git commit -m "first commit"

git branch -M main

git remote add origin https://github.com/mikeyj777/Coursera_DataStructsAndAlgos.git

git push -u origin main
```