# How to connect folder to remote repo?

Tags: git, github

few months ago I moved a project from one server to the other. I just noticed that the .git folder disappeared.

I want to connect that folder back again to the remote repo on GitHub.
I tried to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132956/how-to-connect-local-folder-to-git-repository-and-start-making-changes-on-branch), but it doesn't work in my case.

I created a new `git init`.
The I run `git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/theRepo`

Then if I run git status I get all the files I have in red as Untracked files:
:

```
git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
...........
```

Then I run: `git fetch --all`

```
Fetching origin
Username for 'https://github.com': myusername
Password for 'https://myusername@github.com':
remote: Enumerating objects: 171, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (171/171), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (111/111), done.
remote: Total 171 (delta 39), reused 162 (delta 30), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (171/171), 3.98 MiB | 2.61 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (39/39), done.
From https://github.com/myusername/myRepo
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
```

then I run  `git branch` and there is no output.
`git status` still says all my files are untracked.

In these months few of my local files are newer than the repo. Were edited locally (it's a wordpress theme).

How can I make it to see only the files that are different be in red so that I can push to the repo only the files that are really different?

Or maybe it's better to create locally a new branch, push everything to the new branch, and then compare the two branches in github and in case of need -> merge?

Either way, can anyone please help to make it happen?

If I run `git checkout master`:

```
    git checkout master
    error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
and here the big list of files (all files)
```

then if I run again:

```
 git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
```

Comment: You probably need to checkout a branch? The local master/main branch is empty.

Comment: I just did it. I updated the original question. In the repo there is only 1 branch : master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second impulse was the right one. Create the `.git` repo with `init`, rename `master` to something else like `temp`, add everything, and commit. Add your remote, fetch, and checkout `master`. Now merge, allowing unrelated histories and using the `theirs` option.

So delete the `.git` repo and start over:

```
% rm -rf .git
% git init
% git branch -M master temp
% git add .
% git commit -m'temp'
% git remote add origin git@github.com:you/yourrepo.git
% git fetch
% git switch master
% git merge --allow -X theirs temp
% git branch -d temp
% git push origin master
```

Comment: I followed, but I got until this point and got error:

`git switch master`
`fatal: invalid reference: master`

Comment: Maybe git checkout origin/master

Comment: `git checkout origin master`
`error: pathspec 'origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Comment: You said you could do the fetch and that you got `From https://github.com/myusername/myRepo * [new branch] master -> origin/master`. Is that not true? Maybe you could edit your question to show the whole conversation with Git, both what you said and what Git replied.

Comment: If I run now `git fetch --all` it asks for my github username and password. When I put the credentials it connects and.... ` * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master`

Comment: Then you do have `origin/master`.

Comment: I did exactly what you said. First with the mistake `origin master` then correctly `git checkout origin/master`  as you can see I edited the comment immediately after I realized that spelling mistake.

Comment: If I run `git branch -a` I get: `* temp` and `remotes/origin/master`

Comment: that is totally cool and `git checkout origin/master` should work - unless maybe you are using some really old version of Git? Maybe we could be very literal and say `git branch master origin/master` and then `git checkout master`. Sorry, I can't figure out why this is a blocker; I assure you I actually enacted this whole thing and it worked fine exactly as I have it.

Comment: I am running `git version 2.30.0. Now that I run again `git checkout origin/master` -> `Note: switching to 'origin/master'. You are in 'detached HEAD' state.` and other things, ending with `HEAD is now at c98c2e8 done`. What would be the next step?

Comment: Well then say `git branch master` and `git checkout master`.

Comment: `Switched to branch 'master'` - `git status` says `On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: Yep, so on you go with the `merge` etc.

Comment: Is there any way I can do the merge in GitHub? Here I have many files and I have access to the server only via CLI, no IDE that I can use to help in the merge

Comment: If you do what I said the merge will just happen. You disconnected from GitHub and worked locally only so the local version should be "right", and that is what my `merge` assumes.

Comment: after running `git merge --allow -X theirs temp` I get `Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.`

Comment: well darn, that was what `theirs` was supposed to prevent :( for now you'd better abort the merge I guess

Comment: You can probably push `temp` to GitHub, turn that into a pull request, and work on it using the web interface to GitHub, but I'm not sure what happens about the unrelated history

Answer (score 1):

to see all your branches, go like this after you fetch

```
git branch -a
```

You don't have any of your own branches, but all the branches on origin (github) are downloaded, and have names that start with `origin/`

something like this might work, but maybe back up your whole folder first:

```
git checkout -b new-branch # I don't know how necessary this is
git reset origin/master # make new-branch the same as master
git checkout master # now we can probably just swatch underneath to master
```

If the last command doesn't work, you might still see what you want to see

I haven't tried it, but that is probably what I would do.

---

Another option is just to `git clone` the repo into another folder, and then copy all of your files into that folder with master already checked out (but make sure you don't copy `.git` that you just created

```
cd ..
mv theRepo theRepo.bak
git clone https://github.com/myusername/theRepo
git checkout master # probably done already
cp -r ../theRepo.bak/* .
```

that should copy everything that doesn't start with a `.`.. if you have files that start with a `.` that you need to update, then maybe grab them one by one so you don't accidentally grab the `.git` directory from your last init and fetch